# Who officially authorizes a prophet and how?

Tags: nevua-prophecy

Following "[test-a-true-prophet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108611/what-magnitude-of-a-test-a-true-prophet-must-be-tested)",

After reading Rambam (Yesodey Hatora) that describes the idea of prophecy and prophethood, I understood, that at some point of time a "prophecizing" person must become an official prophet, so everyone must listen to him and fulfil his commands, etc.

In the times of prophets (from Moses to the beginning of the Second Temple), what institute authorized newly emerging prophets? Was it Sanhedrin, was it the King, was it another authorized prophet?

Comment: That's already answered in your first question.  "Interestingly enough, Rambam mentions that if a Prophet is sent to communicate to someone or a group, it is the intended recipient who is to judge the veracity of the Prophet."

Comment: It seems from the Rambam that each person has to decide on his own if this person fulfils the conditions to be called a novi, and if he does you have to listen to him.